# Socket.Send and Receive.. How do i proceed further?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I have to write a program to check if any random string is present in a file. And i did so.. But now i was asked to use sockets.send and receive method. I've created a connection and written the code till here.. How do i proceed further? I'm not able to figure it out.. The first program is my try at server side program. And the second is my actual program to search for a string from the file. Could someone help me with the code on how to use the sockets in my actual program? Thanks alot.. :)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpListener serversocket = new TcpListener(8888);
        int requestcount = 0;
        TcpClient clientsocket = default(TcpClient);
        serversocket.Start();
        Console.WriteLine(">> Server Started");
        clientsocket = serversocket.AcceptTcpClient();
        Console.WriteLine("Accept Connection From Client");
        requestcount = 0;


        while ((true))
        {
            try
            {
                requestcount = requestcount + 1;
                NetworkStream networkstream = clientsocket.GetStream();
                byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
                networkstream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientsocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
                string dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
                dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));
                Console.WriteLine(" >> Data from client - " + dataFromClient);
                string serverResponse = "Server response " + Convert.ToString(requestcount);
                Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverResponse);
                networkstream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
                networkstream.Flush();
                Console.WriteLine(" >> " + serverResponse);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
        clientsocket.Close();
        serversocket.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(" >> exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
       }
  }
```

This is the program i want to use in the above program.

class Program
    {

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (File.Exists("C://myfile2.txt"))
        {
            var text = File.ReadAllText("C://myfile2.txt");


            foreach (var word in new[] { "and", "so", "not", "c", "to", "by", "has", "do", "behavior", "dance", "france", "ok","thast", "please","hello","system","possible","impossible","absolutely","sachin","bradman","schumacher","http","console","application" })
            {
                var w = word;

                new Thread(() => Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", w, text.Contains(w) ? "Present" : "Not Present")).Start();
            }

        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("File Does not exist");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

Comment: How are the two code blocks related ?

Comment: please tag as homework if appropriate, otherwise you'll get unhelpful answers (saying: don't reinvent the wheel, e.g.)

Comment: @sehe Its not homework. Just got into my first job. I'm a novice.

Comment: @3692 so, in effect it is an exercise on the job? I can advise that the socket loop is infinite, and the lower program is horrifically inefficient. Let me know if you want more ideas, I could post it as an answer

Comment: @sehe no its not that. In my previous post, i was asked to learn about how to create a connection. And i did. But i'm unable to figure out how to go about it.

Comment: @sehe I'd be really glad if u helped me out with more ideas.. :) Hope u could understand what i actually wanted?

Comment: @3692 Added more notes, as per your request, see answer

Comment: @sehe I really appreciate your help.. :) Thanks a ton. :) I will make sure to imply everything u suggested and make the program more efficient. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty idea that I wrote without an IDE (---I haven't tested it--- **Edit** just tested it with netcat, and it works fine):

- Note it uses a regular expression. If the lookup table for words grows sufficiently large, you'd be better of storing the words in a `HashSet<string>` and splitting the input into words. You can then efficiently do a `.IntersectWith` to see whether any of the words are matched.
- Note that the socket's constructor is deprecated (you are supposed to explicitely specify and IPAddress to bind to)
- Your original code doesn't require matches to be separate words (`candy` matches both `c` and `and`). You might want to fix that
- The parts that were inefficient in the original 'grep' snippet:

  - ReadAllText (won't scale for large files)
  - Doing multiple `.Contains` calls in a loop will be far less efficient than using a (precompiled) regular expression
  - Why on earth are threads being created there? This will literally only add runtime overhead and potentially lead to problems due to the unsynchronized access to `Console.Out`.

.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Net.Sockets;

class Program
{
    private static Regex _regex = new Regex("and|so|not|c|to|by|has|do|behavior|dance|france|ok|thast|please|hello|system|possible|impossible|absolutely|sachin|bradman|schumacher|http|console|application", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpListener serversocket = new TcpListener(8888);
        TcpClient clientsocket = default(TcpClient);
        serversocket.Start();
        Console.WriteLine(">> Server Started");
        clientsocket = serversocket.AcceptTcpClient();
        Console.WriteLine("Accept Connection From Client");

        try
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(clientsocket.GetStream()))
            {
                string line;
                int lineNumber = 0;
                while (null != (line = reader.ReadLine()))
                {
                    lineNumber += 1;
                    foreach (Match match in _regex.Matches(line))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Line {0} matches {1}", lineNumber, match.Value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

        clientsocket.Close();
        serversocket.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(" >> exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help.. :) Thanks a ton. :) I will make sure to imply everything u suggested and make the program more efficient. :)

Comment: Just had a small doubt, where and how do i read the file here? The file where the strings should be checked for..

Comment: @3692 my sample does the read from socket, as per your question: "But now i was asked to use sockets.send and receive method". I tested it with a command line client using `netcat localhost 8888 < c:\testfile.txt` and it worked fine. If you want a C# client as well (why?) then just go back [to the site where you got the server code from](http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-client-socket.htm). I might add a simple client stub if I find the time (at work)

Comment: Thank u.. :) I tried opening the file like the way u asked me to, `telnet localhost 5656 < C:\myfile2.txt` but the server connection closes if i try doing that and the file doesn't open. Why is that? And what should i do?

Comment: after i give the command line `telnet localhost 5656 <c:\myfile2.txt`, it directly goes to ` >> exit` in the output screen..

Comment: @3692 Telnet is not a suitable program for that. Use netcat or just write a client in C# or whatever other language (that is the purpose of sockets anyway: platform independent communication channels)

Comment: I modified your program such that it now accepts multiple clients. Its working fine on that. But i'm still not able to figure it out on how to modify the whole program such that it works on TelNet.. Can u please help me out? Shall i re-post the whole code i modified?

Comment: You could. However, telnet is not intended for non-interative use (read: input/output redirection will be troublesome). You could use the unix tools expect/script to fake it, but I get the distinct impression you'd really need netcat

Comment: This is how i've modified the program. Could u please look through it and tell me if its right. Here's the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906234/socket-accepts-multiple-clients-but-im-unable-able-to-open-the-file)