# Socket accepts Multiple Clients, but i'm unable able to open the file

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

Basically I've written this program to check for strings. I've used socket method for this.

The problem is, I am unable to figure out how and where exactly to open the file in this program and search for the strings. Instead of giving the search string in the program, I want the client to be able to type/search for any strings they want. And when I run the program, I need the output on client's screen.

How can I improve this program? Could someone please help me out with the code?

This is my program :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpListener serversocket = new TcpListener(8888);
        TcpClient clientsocket = default(TcpClient);
        serversocket.Start();
        Console.WriteLine(">> Server Started");
        while (true)
        {
            clientsocket = serversocket.AcceptTcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("Accept Connection From Client");
            LineMatcher lm = new LineMatcher(clientsocket);
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(lm.Run));
            thread.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Client connected");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(" >> exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
        clientsocket.Close();
        serversocket.Stop();
    }
}
public class LineMatcher
{
    private static Regex _regex = new Regex("not|http|console|application", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
    private TcpClient _client;
    public LineMatcher(TcpClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(_client.GetStream()))
            {
                string line;
                int lineNumber = 0;
                while (null != (line = reader.ReadLine()))
                {
                    lineNumber += 1;
                    foreach (Match match in _regex.Matches(line))
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine("Line {0} matches {1}", lineNumber, match.Value);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Closing client");
        _client.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no client code. The client code is (usually) another application, because that is where (network) sockets shine.

Comment: @sehe Can u help me with that? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple demo client that works for me:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace AClient
{
    class Client
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            using (var client = new TcpClient("localhost", 8888))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(">> Client Started");

                using (var r = new StreamReader(@"E:\input.txt", Encoding.UTF8))
                using (var w = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    string line;
                    while (null != (line = r.ReadLine()))
                    {
                        w.WriteLine(line);
                        w.Flush(); // probably not necessary, but I'm too lazy to find the docs
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine(">> Goodbye");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much sehe. :) I'm really happy u helped me through out. :) Wish atleast once in the future, i will be able to answer any question of urs.. lol.. still a novice till then.. :)